# RethinkDB: merge two tables if one does not contains key of other

Tags: node.js, database, rethinkdb

I am merging two tables
Table 1's primary key exists in table 2 but in some case there is no key foreign in table 2. Which fires error that there is no key exists.
I want to merge table with condition only if key exists;

```
    r.table('sport').filter({sport_id:sport_id}).merge(function(doc){
    return {
        terminology: r.table('sport_terminology').get(doc("terminology_id"))
    }
})
    .run(conn, sport);
```

Now if sport does not contain terminology as key than it is firing error. Please give me solution for merge bypass if key does not exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit unclear from your question what is it that you're having trouble with, since you haven't posted the exception you're getting.

I assume that for some documents, you're getting a "No attribute 'terminology_id' in object". If that's the case, simply add  a `default()` value, e.g:

```
r.table('sport').filter({sport_id:sport_id}).merge(function(doc) {
  return {
    terminology: r.table('sport_terminology')
      .get(doc("terminology_id").default(null))
  }
})
```

If it's not the case, please post the error message.

Comment: why don't you use `getAll` ? `r.table('sport').getAll("sport_id",{index:"sport_id"})`. That will speed up your query(sorry your search) and of course other merge part stays the same.